# contextmanager vs __enter__()/__exit__()

Tags: python

Есть два варианта для реализации менеджера контекста:

1. С помощью декоратора `@contextmanager`
2. С помощью написания методов `__enter__()` и `__exit__()`

Мне бы хотелось узнать мнение опытных, когда лучше использовать п.1, а когда п.2 ?

Я пока исхожу из соображений, что если код небольшой и можно поместить в одну функцию, тогда п.2.

Comment: contextmanager для функций, __enter__ для классов. А вообще contextmanager просто оборачивает (func, args, kwds) в класс, где есть методы enter exit. Те тоже самое что и второй вариант. Посмотреть можно в contextlib.py - class _GeneratorContextManager(ContextDecorator)

Comment: Вы непоняли сути вопроса. Вы отвечаете на вопрос "Как?", а я не этот вопрос написал. Все мы знаем, что одну и туже задачу можно решить различными способами. Вот в вопросе задал именно это: какой более предпочтительный?

Comment: Не совсем понятно. Если код небольшой и можно поместить в одну функцию это как раз п1. А вот если большой, реализованный классом, тогда п2. И вообще, проще, значит лучше, а проще п2.

Comment: @vadimvaduxa: Так-то оно так, но разве вы на практике не сталкивались с ситуацией, когда казалось бы очевидной и логичное решение с течением времени кем-то отвергается, аргументируется и вам только и остается подвигать плечами со словами "Не знал о таком нюансе". Да. Мне тоже очевидно то что вы написали, но мне хочется глубже понять свое ремесло и чем больше нюансов знаю, тем лучше для меня!

Answer (score 1):

`@contextmanager` обычно удобнее, реализацию с классами возможно стоит использовать, если хочется проинспектировать бэктрейс, не заглядывая в `traceback`.

Чуть более конкретно:

1. Если менеджер используется для RAII, важно окружать `yield` блоком `try-finally`
2. Если нужно подавлять исключение определенного типа, это можно сделать с помощью `except`
3. Состояние, которое в реализации напрямую через классы бы сохранялось в полях класса, естественнее хранить в локальных переменных функции-генератора.

Подробнее:

- [Fluent Python](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0131L3PW4)

  - [Перевод](http://dmkpress.com/catalog/computer/programming/python/978-5-97060-384-0/)
- [PEP-343](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0343/)

  - Включает реализацию `@contextmanager`

Comment: можно и в `@contextmanager` в `except` ветке проинспектировать исключение и при желании иногда позволить ему всплыть (просто `raise` без параметров). Отличие  по сравнению с реализацией `__enter__()/__exit__()` можно увидеть, к примеру, если повторно передать в `with` тот же объект (`@contextmanager` один раз только передать можно).

Comment: @jfs верно, я спутал с плюсами, где в зависимости от реализации бектрейса `throw` может потерять стек-трейс.

Comment: @AlexeiAverchenko: Можете пояснить п.1. ? Неуверен что верно понимаю вашу мысль

Comment: @sys_dev если вы хотите выполнить какие-то действия в независимости произошло исключение или нет внутри with-блока, то реализовать в \@contextmanager это можно с помощью try/finally (окружающего yield). В блоке finally можно закрыть файлы, соединения, итд. в независимости произошло исключение или нет. RAII состоит в том что до yield вы какой-то объект собираете, а после yield в finally разбираете его. Без finally, утечка ресурсов могла бы быть в случае исключения внутри тела with-блока.

Comment: @jfs: Другими словами корректное завершение сущестования ресурса забросить в `__enter__`. Все вернО? Если так, то разве `__exit__` не для этой задачи предназначен?

Comment: @sys_dev: нет. `__enter__` может создать объект, `__exit__` разобрать. То что после `yield`  в функции с @contextmanager декоратором написано -- это часть к `__exit__` относится. Посмотрите на [иллюстрирующий код в docstring](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3e0f1fc4e0ffcfcc706015fa3d67c262948ef171/Lib/contextlib.py#L131-L157)

Comment: @jfs: То есть этот случай про п.1 в моем вопросе и Alexei Averchenko в его ответе в п.1. нужно указать об этом более явно

Comment: @sys_dev учитывая что yield внутри` __enter__/__exit__` вы маловероятно встретите, а в функции с \@contextmanager декоратором почти наверняка yield присутствует, то очевидно о чём речь, когда yield упоминается.

Answer (score 0):

Ответ моего коллеги известного как **ysegorov**:

`__enter__/__exit__` - когда есть необходимость хранить какое-то состояние в инстансе и сам объект может использоваться не только в менеджере контекста
самый хороший пример - транзакция в базе.

На `__enter__` создается курсор, внутри контекста делаются операции и на выходе делается commit или rollback в зависимости от состояния операции

В качестве примера можно посмотреть реализацию класса [PgTransaction](https://github.com/ysegorov/jukoro/blob/develop/jukoro/pg/db.py#L209) на GitHub.

Comment: Если объект не только как context manager используется, то не важно есть дополнительное внутреннее состояние или нет (если вы хотите дополнительные методы определять, то логично класс использовать). В противном случае, состояние прекрасно в локальных переменных можно хранить в @contextmanager